# Multer re.file Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am in need of some assistance. I am using react on the front end and node js on the back end with MySQL as the database. In node js, I am using multer to file transfer, but multer returns undefined for the file. I am not sure if it is because I am trying to transfer extra information within the Axios post section. My code is attached, any help will be greatly appreciated.

React Js file:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './Properties_Upload.css';
import Navbar from '../../../Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Footer from '../../../Components/Footer/Footer';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Properties_Upload() {
    const [addressLine, setAddressLine] = useState('');
    const [addressLine2, setAddressLine2] = useState('');
    const [addressCity, setAddressCity] = useState('');
    const [addressState, setAddressState] = useState('');
    const [addressZipCode, setAddressZipCode] = useState('');
    const [mlsID, setMLSID] = useState('');
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const propertyInfoHandler = async () => {
        const data = new FormData() 

        for (var x = 0; x < selectedFile.length; x++) {
            data.append('file', selectedFile[x]);
        }

        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/property/properties_upload', data, {
            addressLine: addressLine,
            addressLine2: addressLine2,
            addressCity: addressCity,
            addressState: addressState,
            addressZipCode: addressZipCode,
            mlsID: mlsID
        })
        .then((response) => {
            navigate('/properties');
            if (response.data.errorMessage){
                setErrorMessage(response.data.message);
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <div className='propertiesUploadBody'>
                <h1>Properties Upload</h1>
                <div className='propertyInfoFormBody'>
                    <h1>Property Information</h1>
                    <p className='addressLine'> *Property address: <input name='addressLine' placeholder='Address' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressLine(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressLine2'> Apartment/Suite/Unit: <input name='addressLine2' placeholder='Apartment/Suite/Unit' autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressLine2(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressCity'> *Property city: <input name='addressCity' placeholder='City' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressCity(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressState'> *Property state: <input name='addressState' placeholder='State' maxLength={2} required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressState(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressZipCode'> *Property zip code: <input type='number' name='addressZipCode' placeholder='Zip Code' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressZipCode(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='propertyMLSID'> MLS ID: <input type='number' name='propertyMLSID' placeholder='MLS ID' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setMLSID(e.target.value)} /></p>
                </div>
                <div className='propertyFileFormBody'>
                    <h1>Property Image Upload</h1>
                    <p> Upload Images of the property.</p>
                    <input className='uploadFiles' type='file' name='file' multiple required onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files)} />
                </div>
                <h2 style={{color: "red"}}>{errorMessage}</h2>
                <button className='uploadButton' onClick={propertyInfoHandler}>Upload Property</button>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

Node Js File:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const SqlDbStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
//----------------------------------------- BEGINNING OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
    store: new SqlDbStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: '**************',
    database: '**************',
    }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie:{
        maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
        secure: false
    }
}));
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './Images');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname );
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('file');
//----------------------------------------- END OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
router.post('/properties_upload', (req, res) => {
  const address = req.body.addressLine;
  const address2 = req.body.addressLine2;
  const city = req.body.city;
  const state = req.body.state;
  const addressZipCode = req.body.addressZipCode;
  const mlsID = req.body.mlsID;
  const rentalID = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
  // const imageFiles = req.body.data;

  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return res.status(500).json(err)
    } else if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err)
    }
    console.log("fileInfo: " + req.file);
    return res.status(200).send(req.file)
  });
  
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly Configured Setup

React JS file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './Properties_Upload.css';
import Navbar from '../../../Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Footer from '../../../Components/Footer/Footer';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Properties_Upload() {
    const [addressLine, setAddressLine] = useState('');
    const [addressLine2, setAddressLine2] = useState('');
    const [addressCity, setAddressCity] = useState('');
    const [addressState, setAddressState] = useState('');
    const [addressZipCode, setAddressZipCode] = useState('');
    const [mlsID, setMLSID] = useState('');
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const propertyInfoHandler = () => {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/property/properties_upload';
        const data = new FormData() 

        for (var x = 0; x < selectedFile.length; x++) {
            data.append('files', selectedFile[x]);
        }

        Axios.post(url, data, {
            addressLine: addressLine,
            addressLine2: addressLine2,
            addressCity: addressCity,
            addressState: addressState,
            addressZipCode: addressZipCode,
            mlsID: mlsID
        })
        .then((response) => {
            navigate('/properties');
            if (response.data.errorMessage){
                setErrorMessage(response.data.message);
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <div className='propertiesUploadBody'>
                <h1>Properties Upload</h1>
                <div className='propertyInfoFormBody'>
                    <h1>Property Information</h1>
                    <p className='addressLine'> *Property address: <input name='addressLine' placeholder='Address' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressLine(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressLine2'> Apartment/Suite/Unit: <input name='addressLine2' placeholder='Apartment/Suite/Unit' autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressLine2(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressCity'> *Property city: <input name='addressCity' placeholder='City' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressCity(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressState'> *Property state: <input name='addressState' placeholder='State' maxLength={2} required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressState(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressZipCode'> *Property zip code: <input type='number' name='addressZipCode' placeholder='Zip Code' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressZipCode(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='propertyMLSID'> MLS ID: <input type='number' name='propertyMLSID' placeholder='MLS ID' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setMLSID(e.target.value)} /></p>
                </div>
                <div className='propertyFileFormBody'>
                    <h1>Property Image Upload</h1>
                    <p> Upload Images of the property.</p>
                    <input className='uploadFiles' type='file' name='file' multiple required onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files)} />
                </div>
                <h2>{errorMessage}</h2>
                <button className='uploadButton' onClick={propertyInfoHandler}>Upload Property</button>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

Node JS file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const SqlDbStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
//----------------------------------------- BEGINNING OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
    store: new SqlDbStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: '**************',
    database: '**************',
    }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie:{
        maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
        secure: false
    }
}));
const multerDestination = './routes/Images/';
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, files, cb) {
    cb(null, multerDestination);
  },
  filename: function (req, files, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + files.originalname );
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('files');
//----------------------------------------- END OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
router.post('/properties_upload', (req, res) => {
  const address = req.body.addressLine;
  const address2 = req.body.addressLine2;
  const city = req.body.city;
  const state = req.body.state;
  const addressZipCode = req.body.addressZipCode;
  const mlsID = req.body.mlsID;
  const rentalID = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;

  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return res.status(500).json(err)
    } else if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err)
    }
    console.log("fileInfo: " + req.files);
    return res.status(200).send(req.files)
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Multer as a middleware in the endpoint where you want to upload files. Also, if you want to upload only one file, you should use `single` instead of `array` when configuring Multer.

```js
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

...

router.post('/properties_upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  
  console.log('File: ', req.file);
  
});
```

---

If you want to upload multiple images, you should use `array` method of the Multer:

```js
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

...

router.post('/properties_upload', upload.array('files'), (req, res) => {

  console.log('Files: ', req.files);

});
```

**Note:** Multer will now populate `req.files` and not `req.file`.

Also, you should send all the images under the `files` property as array. You can do it like this:

[image]

Comment: This does work perfect, especially if I change the storage line alone from array to single. However, I want to upload multiple images, and that’s where I’m having the issue.

Comment: I updated my answer, can you try it again?

Comment: So it's now returning blank... but no files are being moved into the image folder.

Comment: Did you select which files you want under the `VALUE` for each file? Also did you change the name of the field in Multer's method `upload.array('files')`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have been moving and unpacking. So on the frontend, would I select which files I want under the value using a for loop? I did change the name of the field in the multer method.

Comment: You can also use Multer's `.any()` method that will enable you to enter any file names: `upload.any()`

Comment: That one didn't work